# How to get JAVA object from OResultSet

Tags: java, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have the following code. And problem is that I was unable to find any documentation on how to extract/cast OResult to my java type and get pojo.

```
OrientDBObject orientDBObject;
try (ODatabaseObject databaseObjectInner = orientDBObject.open(dbName,     username, password)) {
    specFromDB = getEntitySpecInt3(databaseObjectInner, objectId, rid);
    try (OResultSet resultSet = databaseObject.query(queryByRid)) {
        if (!resultSet.hasNext()) {
            return null;
        }

        Object specObj = resultSet.next();

        // how to cast properly?
        return (EntitySpec) specObj;
        }
    }
```

How to cast or get object from OResult?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OrientDB v 3.0 you have two ways to do it.

The easy one: just use `db.objectQuery()` instead of `db.query()`, it just returns POJOs.

The second way is to extract the OIdentifiable from the OResult and then use `db.getUserObjectByRecord()` to convert it to a POJO:

```
OResult item = resultSet.next();
OIdentifiable doc = item.toElement();
Object pojo = db.getUserObjectByRecord(doc, null);
```

Comment: Thanks @Luigi Dell'Aquila. db.objectQuery() is what i want!